# What does fractional notation represent in molecular formulas such as SiO4/2 or H2SiO2/2?

Tags: lewis-structure, structural-formula, chemical-formula

I'm going through some papers about HSQ (hydrogen silsesquioxane) and keep seeing this fractional notation being used:
HSiO<sub>3/2</sub> , SiO<sub>4/2</sub> , H<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>2/2</sub> , H<sub>3</sub>SiO<sub>1/2</sub>.

[Example paper](https://www.physik.hu-berlin.de/de/x-ray/publications/pdf/caster_kowarik_jramanspectroscopy_2009_hsq_cars.pdf).

I understand that the proper formula for HSQ is [HSiO<sub>3/2</sub>]<sub>2n</sub>. Because we can't have fractional atoms, it's always multiplied by an even number and as such the fraction is never a consideration. But then why are the fractions maintained in the other compounds, and not reduced to SiO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>SiO ?

Does keeping the fraction confer some structural information ? I've tried to find out what this notation means, but could not find a proper explanation.

Edit: What do the numerator and denominators mean, formally, in those formulas ? If it's that the oxigen atoms share outside bonds, why not write the compound as SiO<sub>4</sub><sup>−4</sup> ? If the numerator is the number of atoms, what does the denominator represent ? And is it always /2 ? Can we have /x , where x is a different integer ? I've never seen this type of notation before. Does the denominator mean that the valence electrons are halved ?

Comment: Well, yes, it does confer certain structural information. You don't have an entity SiO2, for example. What you have is an entity SiO4 in which all oxygen atoms are shared with others.

Comment: So then what does the /2 in $SiO_{4/2}$ mean ? I've never seen the fractional notation before. What is it telling us ? That all of the oxigen atoms are shared ? Why "4/2" then if they all share outside bonds ? Why not write it as $SiO_{4}^{−4}$ ? If the numerator is the number of atoms, what does the denominator represent ? Right until now I've only seen whole numbers in the subscripts, not fractions. Just trying to understand what it represents formally. And is it always /2 ? Can we have /x , where x is a different integer ?

Comment: 4 stands for **four** oxygens, 2 means that each oxygen is shared between **two** SiO4 entities, and we don't write $\ce{SiO4^4-}$ because that's a thing we don't have here either. (We may have it elsewhere, but that's another story.)

Comment: "oxygen is shared between **two** SiO4 entities". Well if you look at the linked paper's figure 1 where they draw out the cage, there's only one $SiO_{4}$ entity. The oxigen atoms are not shared with another $SiO_{4}$ entity, they connect to a $H_{3}SiO_{1/2}$, or a $HSiO_{3/2}$. I am really confused by this notation becaus I've not seen it in any textbook, and it's not formally defined. It just seems like something they came up with and this "number of atoms/shared valence electrons" is a bit hand-wavy.

Comment: If the denominator trully means atoms are shared, then isn't it more valid to write $[SiO_{4}]2n$ ? And does the denominator always have to be 2, or can we have $RSiO_{3/X}$ (Taking $HSiO_{3/2}$ as an example) where R = alkyl, halide, alkoxide, etc., and the Si is connected to 3 oxigen atoms but the oxigen is shared in between **X** entities ? The fraction is really throwing me off.

Comment: Also, "You don't have an entity SiO2, for example". I was under the impression that the structure of $SiO_{2}$ was a Si-O cage. That means a Si connected to 4 Oxigen atoms, exactly the same way our $SiO_{4/2}$ is structured. The reason it reduces to $SiO_{2}$ is because those structures repeat and are connected through Si-O-Si bonds to others, making the overall balance of atoms in the compound to equal $SiO_{2}$. [Link to the Si-O cage in $SiO_{2}$ showing the same structure as the $SiO_{4/2}$ entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide#/media/File:Si-OCage.svg)

Comment: Would it be correct then to say that silicon dioxide $SiO_{2}$ is made up of $SiO_{4/2}$ entities "in which all oxygen atoms are shared with others." ? Where "4 stands for four oxygens, 2 means that each oxygen is shared between two SiO4 entities," ?

Comment: Indeed, you'd better accept it in a more hand-wavy and less formal way. Even if there is a formal definition out there, this notation is far from being used universally. OK, SiO4/2 means that each oxygen atom is shared between two entities _which do not have to be similar_. Say, between SiO4/2 and HSiO3/2.

Comment: I see, thank you. Would it be fair then to say that the /2 is used to show that the O atom is a [bridging ligand](https://old.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf) ? If so, can these be re-written as $HSi(μ_{2}−O)_{3}$, $Si(μ_{2}−O)_{4}$, $H_{2}Si(μ_{2}−O)_{2}$, and $H_{3}Si(μ_{2}−O)$? Or is that wrong because these formulae refer to particular types of Si environment, and are not empirical formulae for the substance as a whole ?

Comment: The terminology of metal clusters and ligands... well, I guess it can technically be used here, but then it doesn't sit well with writing "clusters" by parts. When you call your "ligand" $\mu_2$, you imply that it is $\mu_2$ _with respect to the whole "cluster"_.